# Use of the pronoun “its”

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, pronouns

Considering the following sentence:

> The availability of alcoholic beverages and the exposure to **alcoholic beverages** media
>   is high in urban areas.

I would like to know if it is grammatically correct to use the pronoun “its” when “alcoholic beverages” appear for the second time:

> The availability of alcoholic beverages and the exposure to **its** media is high
>   in urban areas.

Comment: "Its" is a possessive pronoun, which must refer to some antecedent. Consider: does the media belong to either the availability or the alcoholic beverages?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't work, because *alcoholic beverages* isn't possessive in *alcoholic beverages media* (You haven't written an apostrophe, and that is right).

Alternatively, if you regarded the full phrase as possessive, it would be *alcoholic beverages' media*, with a plural possessor, so the pronoun would have to be *their*. But that would read oddly to me.